# Insert XML data in selected tags

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to insert data in the block of red `<title> DATA HERE </title>`  and in this 
`<description>
   <text> DATA HERE</text>
</description>` 

using Simple XML. Below is a sample of the XML tree-
[image]

Below is my PHP code from creating the XML tags and data from `<question>` onward but I have no clue how to do the above.

```
$questionLoad = $xml->children()[0]->addChild('question');
$textQue = $questionLoad->addChild('text', $que);
$optionNode = $questionLoad->addChild('option');
$ans1 = $optionNode->addChild('text', $answer1);
$score = $optionNode->addChild('score', $score1);
$explain = $optionNode->addChild('explanation');
$expl1 = $explain->addChild('text', $explanation1);

$xml->asXML('test.xml');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

http://3v4l.org/8F5eQ

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quizzes>
    <quiz>
        <title>
        </title>
        <description>
            <text>
            </text>
        </description>
    </quiz>
</quizzes>';

$quizzes = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$quizzes->quiz[0]->title = "TITLE";
$quizzes->quiz[0]->description->text = "DESCRIPTION";

echo $quizzes->asXML();
?>
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quizzes>
    <quiz>
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <description>
            <text>DESCRIPTION</text>
        </description>
    </quiz>
</quizzes>
```

Comment: It is not doing exactly what I need but it has helped me devise a new solution,thank you so much.